# Scala - define implicitNotFound in implicit conversion

Tags: scala, annotations, implicit-conversion

I have a class `Foobar[A, B](x: A)` and an implicit conversion method to turn `Foobar(x) => x` if there is evidence that `A <:< B`.  This currently works, so if I call `Foobar(x).xyzzy` where `xyzzy` is a method defined on x, as long as evidence exists that `A <:< B` the conversion works fine.  My problem is that if no evidence that `A <:< B` exists, invoking `Foobar(x).xyzzy` errors with the message that `xyzzy` is not a member of `Foobar`.  This is true, and I understand why this happens, but I want the error in this case to instead say `Cannot prove A <:< B` or something to that effect.  I think `implicitNotFound` should help me do this, but I'm having trouble making it work.

Example:

```
import scala.language.implicitConversions
class Qwerty[A](val _value: A) {
  def toFoobar[B](func: A => B): Foobar[A,B] = new Foobar[A,B](_value, func)
}

object Qwerty {
  implicit def wrapQwerty[A](anything: A): Qwerty[A] = new Qwerty(anything)
  implicit def unwrapQwerty[A](qwerty: Qwerty[A]): A = qwerty._value
  implicit def unwrapFoobar[A, B >: A](foobar: Foobar[A, B]): B = foobar.func(foobar._value)
}

class Foobar[A, B](val _value: A, val func: A => B) { }

import Qwerty._

println(5.toFoobar(_ + 2) - 1) // works
println(5.toFoobar(_ + "bad type") - 1) // errors (correctly) but I want error message to say "type mismatch"
```

Comment: Can you please provide your code.

Comment: `implicitNotFound` is for type classes, not for views. maybe it's better to use view bound?

Comment: I translated your description into code, and I *do** get the error "Cannot prove that A <:< B" (followed by "value xyzzy is not a member of Foobar"), without doing anything special. So once againt, can you show us your code? And also please specify your scala version.

Comment: uploaded example code

Comment: Well thanks, but your code does not have any `<:<` evidence anywhere. Did I miss something? Also, which scala version are you using?

Comment: Oh sorry - I was toggling between trying `B >: A` and implicit `ev: A <:< B`.  2.10